# MacBuntu icon is not working for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, icon-themes, macbuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am following a web [tutorial](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html) to install Mac theme for Ubuntu. It is MacBuntu-os theme and it is working fine but few icons are not looking good.

below is screenshot..

[image]

You can See that **gimp** (arrow is showing gimp icon above desktop) and **show desktop** is not looking nice as compare to others.

Can anyone please help me to improve this theme.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this happen with other icon packs too such as `Numix`? If no, then it might just be a problem with MacUbuntu icon pack and not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: hmm....it is not happening with other icon pack. So is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Ther might be. You should contact the developer of MacUbuntu icon pack for further assisstance.

Comment: I have posted a comment on that website but there is no reply since yesterday.